# Is there a workaround for the excel's COINTIFS Argument limit

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in one of my cell the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF(F7:F13,"Pass")/COUNTIFS(F7:F13,"<>na")
```

but now I need to add more cells to the Range, and they are not all together so when I tried something like

```
=COUNTIF(F7:F13,G7:G13,F20:F21,C1:C10,XX:XX,YY:YY,ZZ:ZZ,"Pass")/COUNTIFS(F7:F13,"<>na")
```

only allows 4 arguments. How can I bypass this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do multiple countif and add them together.

Comment: @ScottCraner could you give me an example

Comment: `(COUNTIF(F7:F13,"Pass")+COUNTIF(G7:G13,"Pass")+...+COUNTIF(ZZ:ZZ,"Pass"))/COUNTIFS(F7:F13,"<>na")`